# mysql: how create view show tables multiple schema

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I am developing a multi-tenant system that creates a new schema for each new tenant, however I have a unique schema to check if the tenant already exists, in case it does not exist, allow to create a new schema.

Although it works, I "guess" it is not the best solution, I "think" that it would be more interesting to have a view that queries all the "register" table of all the schemas and I use that view to check if the tenant.

In short: I would like to know how to create a view that can query all the "register" tables of each schema and when a new schema is created, that view would be updated. Each new scheme is generated with a random 32-character name.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I question whether creating a new schema for each "tenant" is the right thing to do.  There are definitely circumstances where it is -- these are usually driven by security requirements (which your question does not even allude to).  In general, dividing up data in a database hurts performance, makes the data harder to manage, and impedes updates to the database.

Your question is also unclear on what "register tables" are.  However, you can access all schemas in a database using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/schemata-table.html).  From what you say, you can start with all available schemas and look for the ones that meet your requirements for belonging to a "tenant".